# How to use argmax tensorflow function in 3d array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax, argmax

I want to know how to use `tf.argmax` in 3D array.

My input data is like that:

```
[[[0, -1, 5, 2, 1], [2, 2, 3, 2, 5], [6, 1, 2, 4, -1]], 
[[-1, -2, 3, 2, 1], [0, 3, 2, 7, -1], [-1, 5, 2, 1, 3]]]
```

And I want to get the output of argmax by this input data like this:

```
[[2, 4, 0], [2, 3, 1]]
```

And I want to use `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`function in this format.

How should I use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` function and `tf.equal(tf.argmax)` and `tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tf.argmax` along `axis=3`

```
a = tf.constant([[[0, -1, 5, 2, 1], [2, 2, 3, 2, 5], [6, 1, 2, 4, -1]], 
        [[-1, -2, 3, 2, 1], [0, 3, 2, 7, -1], [-1, 5, 2, 1, 3]]])
b = tf.argmax(a, axis=2)
```